# regexp with russian lang

Tags: php, regex, unicode, cyrillic

I can't solve my problem with regexp.

Ok, when i type:

```
$string = preg_replace("#\[name=([a-zA-Z0-9 .-]+)*]#","$name_start $1 $name_end",$string);
```

everything is ok, except situation with Russian language.

so, i try to re-type this reg-exp:

```
$string = preg_replace("#\[name=([a-zA-Z0-9**а-яА-Я** .-]+)*]#","$name_start $1 $name_end",$string);
```

but this not working,

i know some idea, just write:

```
$string = preg_replace("#\[name=([a-zA-Z0-9йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю .-]+)*]#","$name_start $1 $name_end",$string);
```

but this is crazy :D

please, give me simple variant

Comment: Please share more details, like sample input strings and the expected output corresponding to these strings

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try a Unicode range:

```
'/[\x{0410}-\x{042F}]/u'  // matches a capital cyrillic letter in the range A to Ya
```

Don't forget the /u flag for Unicode.

In your case:

```
"#\[name=([a-zA-Z0-9\x{0430}-\x{044F}\x{0410}-\x{042F} .-]+)*]#u"
```

Note that the STAR in your regex is redundant. Everything already gets "eaten" by the PLUS. This would do the same:

```
"#\[name=([a-zA-Z0-9\x{0430}-\x{044F}\x{0410}-\x{042F} .-]+)]#u"
```

Comment: it's bad, cause it's unreadable! Code must be simple and readable :)

Comment: I think you meant `\x{0401}-\x{042f}` for russian words. `A` indeed is the first character in the russian alphabet, but not in the unicode range. Check the unicode table [here](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Russian_alphabet)

Comment: @Iulian Onofrei, yeah, I indeed see `\x{0401}` in there, but don't see the range `\x{0402}-\x{0409}`. Should it then be `[\x{0401}\x{0410}-\x{042F}]`, or really `[\x{0401}-\x{042F}]` ? Feel free to edit, of course!

Comment: @BartKiers, yes, you're wright. I missed that. I think the correct solution is: `[\x{0430}-\x{044F}\x{0451}]` for lowercase letters and `[\x{0401}\x{0410}-\x{042F}]` for uppercase letters.

Answer (score 7):

The common unicode script (supported since pcre 3.3) provides a test for the property *Cyrillic*.

e.g. replace all characters that are neither cyrillic nor (latin) digits:

```
$string = '1a2b3cйdцeуfкбxюy';
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9\p{Cyrillic}]/u', '*', $string);
```

You can find the documentation for that feature under http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt "Unicode character properties".
And you have to specify the PCRE8 flag (u) as described at http://docs.php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers

Comment: Afaik there are no (technical) differences between the "common" scripts and specifying the ranges "manually". So it's only a matter of choice. Except maybe that the property names are a bit more self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
/^[а-яА-Я\p{Cyrillic}0-9\s\-]+$/
```

I have tested in all the browsers including Safari

Answer (score 0):

Among the most used alphabet in the internet.

This works since a good while now, I believe since php 5.6.

```
// Filter Chinese and Japanese HAN
if (preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", " 余TEST杭丽人广播", $match)){echo "CHINESE, JAPANESE ";}
// Filter Cyrilic
if (preg_match("/\p{Cyrillic}/u", "Күңел радиосы ", $match)){echo "RUSSIAN ";}
// Filter Greek
if (preg_match("/\p{Greek}/u", "Πρακτορείο ", $match)){echo "GREEK ";}
// Filter Arabic
if (preg_match("/\p{Arabic}/u", "مشال راډیو", $match)){echo "ARABIC ";}
// Filter Armenian
if (preg_match("/\p{Armenian}/u", "Ազատություն ", $match)){echo "ARMENIAN ";}
// Filter Thai
if (preg_match("/\p{Thai}/u", "สวท.พะเยา", $match)){echo "THAI ";}
// Filter Georgian
if (preg_match("/\p{Georgian}/u", "რადიო თავისუფალი", $match)){echo "GEORGIAN";}

/* Output: */
/* CHINESE, JAPANESE RUSSIAN GREEK ARABIC ARMENIAN THAI GEORGIAN */
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As far as I see, the OP did not ask for a regular expression to detect a language

Comment: This is the point: no explanation needed.