# Regex not playing well with Russian text

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regexp with russian lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571187/regexp-with-russian-lang)

I have a regular expression that filters out certain links out of a text and attaches a file icon based on the filetype of the link. Like this:

```
$text = preg_replace('((<a href="[\w\./:]+getfile.php\?id='.$file.'"([a-zA-Z0-9_\- ,\.:;"=]*)>)([a-zA-Z0-9_,\.:;&\-\(\)\<\>\'/ ]+)</a>)','\\1'.fileicon($name).'</a> \\1\\3</a> ('.($pagecount?$pagecount."&nbsp;".($pagecount>1?$pages:$page1).", ":"").readable_filesize($size,1).')',$text);
```

this worked great until I tried this with some russian text. The input would be something like:

```
<a href="/site/getfile.php?id=33">Русский</a>
```

But it won't show the icon before the link and file information after the link, making me suspect the regex doesn't play well with Russian text. What could be the case here?

Comment: Russian letters are not in your character class `[a-zA-Z]+`, so that's why they don't match.

Comment: @Tomalak an answer to a duplicate though

Comment: @Gordon: Relevance? A 30.5k user should know that he can either post an answer or not post an answer, but should not post one as a comment...

Comment: @ajreal: I can't believe you're the first one to notice that he's parsing HTML with regex! >.<

Comment: hmm ... I think @mario is a big fan of regex

Comment: @Tomalak A 32k user should also know that he should not answer duplicates and thus mario correctly provided the answer as a comment only and closevoted with the possible duplicate.

Comment: @Gordon: No, if you should not answer duplicates then you should not answer duplicates. Answering them incorrectly is not not answering them!

Comment: @Tomalak well, technically he didnt *answer* the duplicate. He commented. So, all is well.

Comment: @Mario, that should have been an answer :)

Comment: @Gordon: Cyclical argument is cyclical.

Comment: Thanx all! I'll mark the answer as soon as I get to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall use `u` modifier when working with Unicode strings:

```
preg_replace('/>([^<]+)</u', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your character class only allows `[a-zA-Z0-9_,\.:;&\-\(\)\<\>\'/ ]`. There are no russion characters in there.

You can fix this by adding the relevant characters to the class. If you only need to support russian, `\p{InCyrillic}` should do it. If you want all unicode letters, `\p{Letter}`.

Comment: The unicode character classes (and `\pL` would suffice) only work if the `/u` modifier is added however.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your regexp down to something like

```
$re = "~
    (<a\s+href=\".+?getfile\.php\?id=$file\".*?>)
    (.+?)
    </a>
~xui";
```

this should solve the Cyrillic problem automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Cyrillic unicode characters are within the range `\x0400-\x04FF`. Add this range in your character class.